# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() while clicking twice a Button in Aura Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, bug

I have been stuck with this bug for over a week.
When I click a button twice, I get the following error:

Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')]
Callback failed: apex://

This is how the code looks:

SearchComponent.cmp:

```
<lightning:button title="Run Search" label="Run Search" disabled ="{!v.disabledRunSearch}" onclick="{! c.runSearchCheck}" aura:id="runSearchCheck"/>
```

And here I call a child component to display the field values in a table:

```
<c:RenderFieldforSearch indexNumber="{!dataIndex}" column="{!column}" record="{!data}" fieldName="{!column.fieldName}" type="{!column.type}"/>
```

SearchComponent.JS:

```
runINSearchCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
        var getData= component.get("c.runSearch");
        
        getData.setParams({
            'recordId':component.get("v.recordId")
        });

        getData.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state=response.getState();
            var result=response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.isLoading",false);

            if(result != null && result.length>0) {
                component.set("v.SearchCompleted", true);
                component.set("v.SearchFailed", false);
                var newData = [];
                for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    newData.push(here i push some data returned by Apex);
                }
            }

        )};
        $A.enqueueAction(getData);
}
```

RenderFieldforSearch.cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="column" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="label" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="target" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="type" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="indexNumber" type="String" />
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInitF}"/>
    
    <aura:if isTrue ="{!v.type == 'text'}">
        <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.value}" />
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.type== 'date' || !v.type== 'datetime' }">
                <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.value}" month="numeric" day="numeric" year="numeric" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit"/>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <lightning:formattedUrl  name="{!v.column.fieldName+'-'+v.indexNumber}" value="{!v.value}" label="{!v.label}" tooltip="{!v.value}" target="{!v.target}" />
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

RenderFieldforSearch.js:

```
({
    doInitF : function(component, event, helper) {

        var rec = component.get('v.record');
        var columnInfo = component.get('v.column');
        var fieldName = component.get('v.fieldName');
        var type = component.get('v.type');

        component.set('v.value',rec[fieldName]);

        if(type === 'url'){
            component.set('v.label',rec[columnInfo.typeAttributes.label.fieldName]);
            component.set('v.target',columnInfo.typeAttributes.target);
            component.set('v.url',rec[fieldName]);
        }
    }
})
```

When I click the button 'Run Search' for the 1st time, no error is thrown but when I click it for the second time, the table does get refreshed but this error is thrown. If I comment the child component, the error is not thrown. I have used almost an identical child component (RenderFieldforSearch) in a different Aura and I don't get this error even if I click the button more than once.

Thanks for your time!!

I tried putting console logs in every line but I don't see where it breaks. It seems to be related to the Child Component but in a similar Aura I am using almost identical child component and no error is thrown. Apex logs show no error either.

Comment: I removed "name="{!v.column.fieldName+'-'+v.indexNumber}" " from the child component in the <lightning:formattedUrl> and the error is not thrown anymore. It does not make any sense to be honest.